# DB2 Logic Apps connector - unable to update a table without a primary key

Tags: db2, azure-logic-apps

I have a very simple use case to implement: I need to update records in a DB2 database hosted on-premise.
Connecting with DB2 works like a charm, I'm able to query the database/table to check if the record already exists, but I'm not able to update the record because the table has no primary key...
The Logic Apps DB2 connector throws this error: `The specified table has no primary key. Update and delete operations are not supported.`.

The DBA in charge of DB2 told me that there is no PK on tables, just unique indexes.
Sounds like I will not be able to use the DB2 Logic Apps connector...

Please note that I tried to use the DB2 .Net connector in Azure Functions but it is not working (because of missing DLL and wrong nuget packages provided by IBM).
I also tried to see if I can figure this out by using ADF, but unfortunately, the DB2 connector can't be used as a sink, just as a source...

Any ideas?

Comment: Just turn one of the unique indexes to a PK. That's pretty much the same concept anyway.

Comment: I can't: I'm currently doing a POC for the customer and I need to demonstrate that I can reuse what already exists.

Comment: Two distinct issues in your question, choose only one issue per question:  (1) azure-logic-apps needs a PK  to update/delete and the target-table lacks a PK.   (2) you have some issue with the Db2 .Net nuget from IBM. #